# Not sure about value of resistor

Tags: resistors

I'm not sure about value of this resistor, is it 300 ohm?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Hint: what E-series is required to get to 300 ohm? How many bands would that E-series require?

Comment: you could simply check with the color reading method.

Comment: I'm complete dummy in color reading method, that's why I'm asking here. I got 300 ohms but I'm not sure about that. Multimeter shows 100 ohm, so I guess this resistor is dead

Comment: stick a multimeter across it and measure?

Comment: Resistor is burnt so I'm not sure about value I'm getting with multimeter, it says 100 ohm

Comment: Brown-Black-Brown-Gold would be 100Ω, 5%.  Maybe the resistor isn't bad at all.

Comment: @winny 300 ohm is in e24 (and is NOT in E48, E96 or E192), so a 300 ohm resistor with the 4 band code is perfectly plausible (though I don't think the OPs resistor is 300 ohm).

Comment: @PeterGreen Thanks! You are correct, the number of color bands are enough. E24 is uncommon, that’s the thing I want to drive home with OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brown black brown gold would be 100 ohms +/- 5%
Could that be the resistor you have?

I see some heat damage there that can make it hard to read the bands.

Comment: After looking at some similar schematics of circuit where this resistor is located, it seems that resistor is 100 ohms. thanks

Answer (score 3):

is it brown brown black gold? then it should be 11Ohm

[image]

from https://resistorcolorcodecalc.com/

Comment: From right to left: orange?, black, brown, gold? (last two colors seem to be different). Multimeter shows 100 ohm but resistor is burnt so I doubt it's 100 ohm

Comment: Sounds like 300 then... but it's hard to tell from the picture. is there a similar one in the circuit, which you can messure?

Comment: Unfortunately there is only one resistor like that in the circuit. It's from 30 year old VDO tachometer. Tachometer doesn't work so I guess it's because that burnt resistor

Comment: bicycle tachometer?

Comment: diesel engine tachometer

Comment: well give 300Ohm a try - hopefully can't get worse if it is to high...